# Migrating Task list from 2010 to 2013 by creating template

Tags: task-list, list-template, content-migration

I am migrating Task List from 2010 to 2013 by Creating template. But I am not able to see that template in 2013.

Steps:

1. Created template of Task List in 2010.
2. Uploaded the same in 2013 , under Site Setting >> List Template
3. When I am adding an app and searching for that template , not able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is that straight forward.

1. First Export List using Central Admin Backup Restore option (List.cmp)
2. Change extension from cmp to cab
3. Extract files to a folder
4. Open file `SystemData.XML` and change version `14.0.0.0` to `15.0.0.0`
5. Change Build to the Build Version of your server. You can use PowerShell to find it out
6. Now re pack the folder into `.cab` file using CabPack
7. Change extension to cmp
8. Open Management Shell in 2013 and execute below command

   ```
   Import-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl -Path cmpfilepath.cmp -verbose
   ```

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Hi Amal , I am able to migrate all Lists and Libraries with the process which I have mentioned. The only problem I am facing is with Task List.